# VBA How can I call the constructor of a return class from C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have a class in C# with constructor

```
namespace CollectionHandler
{
    public class Dict
    {
        private Scripting.Dictionary dict = new Scripting.Dictionary();

        public Dict()
        {
            dict.Add(1, "Carl Johnson");
            dict.Add(2, "Leon");
            dict.Add(3, "Claire");
            dict.Add(4, "Jill");
            dict.Add(5, "Chris");
            dict.Add(6, "Vrad");
            dict.Add(7, "Aida");
            dict.Add(8, "Ryder");
            dict.Add(9, "Snake");
        }

        public Scripting.Dictionary ReturnDict()
        {
            return dict;
        }
    }
}
```

in VBA, these are my codes.

```vb
Public Sub ShowDictionaries()
    Dim msg As String

    Dim pdict As Dictionary
    Set pdict = New Dictionary

    Dim x As CollectionHandler.Dict
    Set x = New CollectionHandler.Dict ' I thought this is the constructor

    Dim ctr As Long


    Dim key As Variant
    ctr = 0
    For Each key In x.ReturnDict().Keys
        ctr = ctr + 1
        pdict.Add key, x.ReturnDict()(key)
        Dim str1 As String
        str1 = "Key: " & ctr & " Value: " & pdict(ctr) & vbNewLine
        msg = msg & str1
    Next

    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "We Are Items From C#"


End Sub
```

The message box displays blank since the list of dictionary items in C# is in constructor, how can I call the contructor of `CollectionHandler.Dict`?

Comment: Strange, your code looks fine. I'm pretty sure that `New CollectionHandler.Dict` *does* call the constructor (because I'm pretty sure that COM interop can't "avoid" .NET constructors), so I'm curious about the solution to this. Have you tried adding debug output (e.g. a simple message box) to the constructor, to make sure it gets called?

Comment: Try to put the dict initialization in a separate method, and call it alone.

Comment: Where does the Dict class code live? Is it a DLL you are referencing?

Comment: Have you tried to print the value of 'ctr' after the loop?